# Fetch thr AD Group details using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to Search the Active Directory group details based on group name or group email address using C#. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
        // do whatever you need to do with the group
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I have tried that and that is not working :( Here is my code.. Please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: @user2150696: please **update** your original question to include the new code! Don't put code into comments - really really hard to read!